# event-feed in XML format

Tags: python, xml, rss

Tell me how you can add custom fields in the rss-tape?
After all, she has a strict [specification](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/article_134.html).

For example, I need to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8"?>
<feed version="1.1">
  <events>
    <event id="93492" price="true" type="concert">
      <title><![CDATA[Kodaline]]></title>
      <age_restricted>18+</age_restricted>
      <tags>
        <tag>18+</tag>
        <tag>концерт</tag>
        <tag>рок и рок-н-ролл</tag>
      </tags>
      <gallery>
        <image href="***"/>
      </gallery>
      <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
    </event>
  <events>
</feed>
```

those. Roughly speaking events ribbon.

As I guess it can not in any way relate to RSS?
Is there any specification for creating events tapes?
Which, for example, you can sync to the google calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. really.

Set in the RSS specifications strict format .
This is done to unify notifications of new news interface .
A more complete freedom gives XML itself , it is possible to put any data structure .

the strict format not use for events-feed ( such as for RSS-feeds ). For example microsoft use  [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968563(v=office.12).aspx)  .